# Deploying Springboot 3 Gradle to GAE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploying my service to google app engine using spring boot 3 framework
when i'm trying to deploy it to app engine using
`./gradlew appengineDeploy`
the deployment is success, but when i'm trying to hit the api, i got this error
`Error: Unable to access jarfile myservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

here's my build.gradle

my directory path

```
myModule
-gradle
-src
  -main
    -appengine
      -app.yaml
    -java
    -resources
      -application.properties
-build.gradle
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.5.0" // If a newer version is available, use it
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
    id 'jacoco'
}

group = 'com.myproject.myservice'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: "com.google.cloud.tools.appengine"  // App Engine tasks

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:4.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:2.0.20'

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.28.0'
    implementation 'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60:3.5.3'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0'

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
    deploy {   // deploy configuration
        projectId = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
        version = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
    }
}
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: java17
env: standard
instance_class: F1
service: myservice
entrypoint: java -jar myservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
env_variables:
  env: "stg"
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=${sm://my-password}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

i've been using this doc as reference
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/runtime

Comment: Did you follow https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/runtime#application_startup? Where is your jar located

Comment: @bob, yes i've followed that doc, when i try to build it locally it's on build/libs (plain and not plain) & build/staged-app (plain only)